# paypal express checkout: how to change 'cancel and return to Alfredo barco store' to mine?

Tags: paypal, customization, express-checkout

am integrating paypal express checkout (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/) into our website. how do i change the 'cancel and return to alfredo store' to our store name?

am trying the javascript based integration as shown in full interactive demo.

also, in payment page, how do i make paypal show a line showing the payment is for my store:

Something like "You are agreeing to pay $ABC.DE to STORE"

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For production environment I do see the business name in paypal login. So this issue can be closed.